Why Does SHGetKnownFolderPath Fail with Error -2147024894 When Using GUIDs on a Non-English Windows?
import os
import ctypes
import logging
from ctypes import windll, byref, create_unicode_buffer, Structure, c_uint32, c_uint16, c_uint8
from uuid import UUID

# Logging instellen
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)

class GUID(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Data1", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Data2", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Data3", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Data4", ctypes.c_uint8 * 8)
    ]

def string_to_guid(guid_string):
    """Converteer een GUID-string naar een ctypes GUID-structuur."""
    guid = UUID(guid_string)
    return GUID(
        guid.fields[0],
        guid.fields[1],
        guid.fields[2],
        (ctypes.c_uint8 * 8)(*guid.fields[3:])
    )

def get_known_folder_path(folder_id):
    """Haal het pad op van een bekende Windows-map via GUID."""
    try:
        guid = string_to_guid(folder_id)
        path_buf = create_unicode_buffer(260)  # Buffer voor het pad
        result = windll.shell32.SHGetKnownFolderPath(byref(guid), 0, None, byref(path_buf))
        if result == 0:
            path = path_buf.value
            logging.info("Map gevonden: %s", path)
            return path
        else:
            logging.error("SHGetKnownFolderPath fout: %s", result)
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Fout bij ophalen map: %s", e)
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GUID's voor standaard Windows-mappen
    known_folders = {
        "Desktop": "{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}",
        "Documents": "{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}",
        "Pictures": "{33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}",
        "Videos": "{18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}",
        "Downloads": "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}",
    }

    for folder_name, folder_guid in known_folders.items():
        logging.info("Controleren of %s bestaat...", folder_name)
        folder_path = get_known_folder_path(folder_guid)
        if folder_path:
            logging.info("Pad voor %s: %s", folder_name, folder_path)
        else:
            logging.error("Kon het pad voor %s niet ophalen.", folder_name)

I am working on a Python script to retrieve paths for standard Windows folders (e.g., Desktop, Documents, Pictures) using their GUIDs. I use SHGetKnownFolderPath in combination with the GUIDs provided in Microsoft's documentation. However, the function consistently fails with the error code -2147024894 (file not found) when run on a Dutch-language Windows 10 installation.
Here is the core logic of my script:

Convert GUID strings into ctypes GUID structures.

Use SHGetKnownFolderPath to fetch folder paths.
import os
import ctypes
import logging
from ctypes import windll, byref, create_unicode_buffer, Structure, c_uint32, c_uint16, c_uint8
from uuid import UUID

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)

class GUID(Structure):
    """Define a GUID structure compatible with ctypes."""
    _fields_ = [
        ("Data1", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Data2", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Data3", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Data4", ctypes.c_uint8 * 8)
    ]

def string_to_guid(guid_string):
    """Convert a GUID string into a ctypes-compatible GUID structure."""
    guid = UUID(guid_string)
    guid_struct = GUID(
        guid.fields[0],
        guid.fields[1],
        guid.fields[2],
        (ctypes.c_uint8 * 8)(*guid.fields[3:])
    )
    logging.info("GUID string: %s", guid_string)
    logging.info("GUID struct: %s", guid_struct)
    return guid_struct

def get_known_folder_path(folder_id):
    """
    Retrieve the path of a known Windows folder using its GUID.
    Uses the SHGetKnownFolderPath function from the Windows API.
    """
    try:
        guid = string_to_guid(folder_id)
        path_buf = create_unicode_buffer(260)  # Buffer for the path
        result = windll.shell32.SHGetKnownFolderPath(byref(guid), 0, None, byref(path_buf))
        logging.info("Result code: %s", result)
        if result == 0:
            path = path_buf.value
            logging.info("Folder found: %s", path)
            return path
        else:
            logging.error("SHGetKnownFolderPath error: %s", result)
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error retrieving folder: %s", e)
        return None

def debug_system_error():
    """Retrieve additional error details using GetLastError."""
    error_code = windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
    logging.error("GetLastError: %s", error_code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GUIDs for standard Windows folders
    known_folders = {
        "Desktop": "{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}",
        "Documents": "{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}",
        "Pictures": "{33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}",
        "Videos": "{18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}",
        "Downloads": "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}",
    }

    # Test using SHGetKnownFolderPath
    for folder_name, folder_guid in known_folders.items():
        logging.info("Checking if %s exists...", folder_name)
        folder_path = get_known_folder_path(folder_guid)
        if folder_path:
            logging.info("Path for %s: %s", folder_name, folder_path)
        else:
            logging.error("Could not retrieve path for %s.", folder_name)
            debug_system_error()



2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Checking if Desktop exists...
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID string: {B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID struct: <_main_.GUID object at 0x000001DD9FA0F2D0>
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Result code: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - SHGetKnownFolderPath error: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - Could not retrieve path for Desktop.
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - GetLastError: 0
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Checking if Documents exists...
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID string: {FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID struct: <_main_.GUID object at 0x000001DD9FA0F650>
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Result code: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - SHGetKnownFolderPath error: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - Could not retrieve path for Documents.
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - GetLastError: 0
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Checking if Pictures exists...
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID string: {33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID struct: <_main_.GUID object at 0x000001DD9FA0F2D0>
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Result code: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - SHGetKnownFolderPath error: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - Could not retrieve path for Pictures.
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - GetLastError: 0
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Checking if Videos exists...
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID string: {18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID struct: <_main_.GUID object at 0x000001DD9FA0F650>
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Result code: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - SHGetKnownFolderPath error: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - Could not retrieve path for Videos.
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - GetLastError: 0
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Checking if Downloads exists...
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID string: {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - GUID struct: <_main_.GUID object at 0x000001DD9FA0F2D0>
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - INFO - Result code: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - SHGetKnownFolderPath error: -2147024894
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - Could not retrieve path for Downloads.
2024-12-22 19:21:27 - ERROR - GetLastError: 0

this is need research under debugger

For a start, find out what "error: -2147024894" means, maybe that gives you the missing hint.

There is something wrong with your string-to-GUID conversion. Using an input of "{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}" I get an output of data1: B4BFCC3A data2: DB2C data3: 424C data4: B029410000000000. Code to output fields: print("data1: {:08X}".format(guid_struct.Data1)) print("data2: {:04X}".format(guid._structData2)) print("data3: {:04X}".format(guid._structData3)) print("data4: {}".format("".join("{:02X}".format(x) for x in guid_struct.Data4)))

Does it work on English systems?

There was 2 things that was wrong.

The way you create Data4 from the string doesn't work. I simply replaced the GUID by the one defined by comtypes
You didn't call SHGetKnownFolderPath correctly (you need to use a pointer of a pointer of wchar).

from comtypes import GUID
from ctypes import HRESULT, POINTER, WinDLL, byref, wintypes


def get_known_folder_path(folder_id):
    """
    Retrieve the path of a known Windows folder using its GUID.
    Uses the SHGetKnownFolderPath function from the Windows API.
    """
    guid = GUID(folder_id)
    path_buf = wintypes.LPWSTR()

    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath
    shell32 = WinDLL("shell32")
    SHGetKnownFolderPath = shell32.SHGetKnownFolderPath
    SHGetKnownFolderPath.restype = HRESULT
    SHGetKnownFolderPath.argtypes = [POINTER(GUID), wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.HANDLE, POINTER(wintypes.LPWSTR)]

    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemfree
    ole32 = WinDLL("ole32")
    CoTaskMemFree = ole32.CoTaskMemFree
    CoTaskMemFree.restype = None
    CoTaskMemFree.argtypes = [wintypes.LPVOID]

    SHGetKnownFolderPath(byref(guid), 0, None, byref(path_buf))
    path = path_buf.value

    CoTaskMemFree(path_buf)

    return path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GUIDs for standard Windows folders
    known_folders = {
        "Desktop": "{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}",
        "Documents": "{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}",
        "Pictures": "{33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}",
        "Videos": "{18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}",
        "Downloads": "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}",
    }

    for folder_name, folder_guid in known_folders.items():
        folder_path = get_known_folder_path(folder_guid)
        print(f"Path for {folder_name}: {folder_path}")

